# call onclick function in other function with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So, I'm using an onclick function to toggle a div's visibility, like so:

```
<div class="div1" v-show="expandDiv">
<div class="div2"  v-on:click="expandDiv = !expandDiv">
```

This works great, but I'm getting problems when I want to use two on-clicks. I have a button which I want to use to run a function that adds items to a cart (addCart(item)) and I also want this function toggle the visibility of my div. Now, you can't two v-on:click so I created another function:

```
expander() {
   cartAdd(item);
   expandDiv = !expandDiv;              
}
```

when I run this function on my v-on:click it doesn't seem to want to work as it only adds it to the cart, but doesnt expand my div. I'm probably syntactically wrong but I can't find a solution.

Would greatly appreciate some help on this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
this.expandDiv = !this.expandDiv
```